# Reading configuration at runtime

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfx, spfx-webparts, 2019, reactjs

I have created "Search Result Source" in my development & production environment Using that in search REST API with source GUID. Now thing is that source GUID of development & production environment are different.

So I am looking for way to define guid in config file like `web.confing` in C# and reading in SPFx.

This will make easier to read development and production configuration plus it will help to maintain SPFx development

Please note that I am using reactjs as framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `.ts` file with necessary information and import it anywhere in your web-part project.

**Reference**: [AppSettings in your SPFx solutions](https://www.mavention.nl/techblog/appsettings-in-your-spfx-solutions)

**OR**

You can create a property pane field to pass the Result Source GUID and use it in your web-part.

**Reference**: [Make your SharePoint client-side web part configurable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/integrate-with-property-pane)

Comment: You make my day. Solution looks promising right away I will try this solution

Comment: Sure, try and let me know if it works for you.